# In Corda, how can a responder flow pass a message back to the initiator flow if they reject a transaction?

Tags: corda

Suppose I have the following flow pair:

- `Initiator`, who creates a transaction
- `Responder`, who either accepts or refuses to sign the transaction

If the node running the `Responder` flow refuses to sign, how can he pass the reason for his refusal back to the node running the `Initiator` flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node running the `Responder` flow needs to throw a `FlowException`. A `FlowException` is a special exception type that should be thrown in flows when you want the exception's message to be visible to the counterparty.

So in `Responder`, you might write:

```
val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {
    override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
        val counterparty = otherPartyFlow.counterparty
        throw FlowException("I refuse to trade with $counterparty")
    }
}

return subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
```

And in the `Initiator`, you could choose to handle the exception:

```
try {
    val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartyFlow), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))
} catch (e: FlowException) {
    logger.error(e.message)
    TODO("Handle error.")
}
```